# How to identify a thread after running and then stop it in Grails with the executor plugin?

Tags: java, grails

I'm using the executor plugin and there are several jobs executing, however I want to identify each one and stop the job that I selected, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is an easier way but you could create a thread group for all of your executors and make the group a container of all your async tasks (executions). Then instead of  passing a closure to the submit method of the plugin, you would create a named thread inside the ThreadGroup and pass the Thread to the submit. Make the TG being part of your spring context or make it global in one way or another. This way having a reference to the thread group you could get back to any active thread (and by extension to any async executions) by doing an enumerate on your TG and by inspecting the threads enumerated you could get to the thread's name, identifying any particular thread you want. You could then interrupt the thread.